# A2LiX Translations validation not working when all fields are submited as empty

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, a2lix-translation

When I don't provide any of the translatable properties through my submit form, then I get no validation checking, even when I have implemented:

`/**
* @Assert\Valid
*/
protected $translations;`

In config.yml I have:

`default_locale: cs
required_locales: [cs]`

All topics about this problem were giving importance on the @Assert/Valid on $translations property, which I have implemented (I have even tried validation.yml configuration).

Now I realise, that I forgot to add, that I am displaying and submiting the form through Easy Admin bundle. I am not building the form myself. Just configuring Easy Admin settings for my entity. Maybe there's some glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following answer link related to same question:
Collection array name fields validation:
[A2Lix form validation for translations field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245953/how-to-manage-multidimensional-array-name-of-fields-at-server-side-validation-wi)

Answer (score 0):

try adding required option to your easy admin type settings

**- { property: 'translations', type: 'a2lix_translations', type_options: { required: true} }**

Comment: Thank you. It could hack some problems when you really need all the translatable properties required. But doesn't solve proper assertion execution (NotNull, NotBlank, Length etc.).